# Update value in PHP by an array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array of keys
eg `$array_keys = ['a','b','c'];`
I want to update an $array by value from $array_keys
eg `$array[$array_keys[0]][$array_keys[1]][$array_keys[0]] = "new text";`
Trouble is the $array_keys can change in length. 
Is there a way I can get the same result by somehow looping through the keys or filtering the array?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you expect. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly. Here is your solution:

```
$array_keys = ['a','b','c'];
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 3];

function updateArrayByKyes(&$array, $array_keys, $new_value) {
    foreach ($array_keys as $key) {
        if (isset($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = $new_value;
        }
    }
}

updateArrayByKyes($array, $array_keys, 10);
```